# Dispatch Queue and global NSMutableDictionary - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, dispatch-async

I'm trying to use a global NSMutableDictionary from a dispatch queue. However, the items keep coming back NULL.

What I'm trying to do is access an external json file with a dispatch_queue, then populate a UITableView with this info.

Here's what I have

vc.h:

```
@interface viewcontroller {
 NSMutableDictionary *jsonArray;
}
```

vc.m:

```
    #define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1
    #define jsonTest [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sometest.com/test.php"]

    -(void)viewDidLoad {
      dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                            jsonTest];
           [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                                   withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
            // if I run the log here, I can access jsonArry and the log prints correctly
            NSLog(@"City: %@", [jsonArray objectForKey:@"city"];
        });
    }

    -(NSMutableDictionary *)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

        NSError *error;
        jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        return jsonArray;
    }

/********************* Table formatting area **********************/

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.ipTable) { 
        if ([ipArray count] == 0){
            return 1;
        } else { // meta table
            return [ipArray count];
        }
    } else { // IP Meta Data
        return [jsonArray count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if (tableView == self.myTable) {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = NULL;
        if ([ipArray count] == 0) {
            CellIdentifier = @"No Cells";
        } else {
            CellIdentifier = @"IP Cell";
        }

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        if ([ipArray count] == 0)
        {
            [cell.textLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"None Found", nil)];
            return cell;

        } else {

        IPAddr *theip = [ipArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
        NSString *theipname = [theip ipName];
        if ([theipname isEqualToString:@""]) {
            [cell.textLabel setText: [theip ipNum]];
            [cell.detailTextLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"noName", nil)];
        } else {
            [cell.textLabel setText: [theip ipName]];
            [cell.detailTextLabel setText: [theip ipNum]];
        }
        return cell;
        }

    } else { // meta table

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"metaCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        // jsonArray content would go here to fill the cells.
        /******************** something here to fill the cells using jsonArray ********************/
        return cell;
    }

} // END UITAbleViewCell
```

If I access the jsonArray inside the queue, it returns fine and prints the log for the city.
However, if I try to use it outside the queue, it returns NULL.

I'm trying to figure out what is happening, any ideas?

I need to use jsonArray in different methods in the same view, so I need it to be global.

Comment: Do you access jsonArray in the other methods *before* it has been set from the background thread?

Comment: Btw: Does fetchedData return an array or a dictionary?

Comment: It returns a dictionary... sorry, this is from my PHP experience, where a Multidimensional Array = Dictionary

Comment: @martinR No, it's only after the queue runs to I access jsonArray.  It's loading the returning data into a UITableView

Comment: Are you sure? The queue runs asynchronously in the background, so other data source methods such as numberOfRows:inSection: are probably called before the queue has finished.

Comment: I think there's some confusion.  I need to access jsonArray only after the queue has run.  If you think there's a better way to approach it, I'm all for it :)

Comment: why dont u use synchronous way?

Comment: Perhaps add more code and show how and when the dictionary/array is accessed. How do you know when the queue has run? - I would expect a `reloadData` call in `fetchedData:`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll add more.

Comment: @MartinR I just added more code.  I'm also editing the main question to clarify what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly sure that the problem is that the data source methods (`numberOfRowsInSection`,
`cellForRowAtIndexPath`) are called *before* the background thread has finished and
filled the `jsonArray`. Therefore you have to *reload* the table view when the background
thread has finished:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonTest];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *tmpArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Assign new data to data source and reload the table view:
            jsonArray = tmpArray;
            [self.metaTableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

So the table view would be empty initially, and reloaded later when the data has
arrived.

Comment: Thanks!  I still couldn't get the array to work properly, so I ended up going a different route based on your inspiration. I put the queue into a method and am running each item from the dictionary as a global variable.  Might be better this way anyways, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the other method(which is using your jsonarray) through nsnotification...I am not sure there might some other ideas/ways of doing this.But i am presenting what i have in my mind.

Put this code inside your fetchedData method,

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
            [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethod:) name:@"JSonDownloaded" object: jsonArray];
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"JSonDownloaded" object: jsonArray];

-(void)someMethod:(NSNotification *)nspk
{
    NSLog(@"%@",nspk.object);
//Only after this you can able to access the jsonArray.
}
```

Don't forget to unregister the observer.

Comment: But, how does this solve my global dictionary issue?  I need to use this dictionary in other methods.

Comment: @Troy..sorry i took your question in some otherway...now i have edited the answer...why dont use synchronous way to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

`jsonArray` is just an instance variable, but not a property. <strike>Thus, assigning an object to it does not retain it, and the object may be released as soon as the program returns to the run loop.</strike>
<strike>I suggest replacing the iVar by `@property (strong) NSMutableDictionary *jsonArray;` and `@synthesize jsonArray;`, and assigning the object to it by `self.jsonArray = ...`</strike>
EDIT (see comment of Martin R below):
Thus, if you are **not** using ARC, assigning an object to it does not retain it, and the object may be released as soon as the program returns to the run loop.
In this case, I suggest replacing the iVar by `@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary *jsonArray;` and `@synthesize jsonArray;`, and assigning the object to it by `self.jsonArray = ...`

Comment: That would only make a difference if OP is still using manual reference counting. With ARC, instance variables are strong by default.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner, I am using ARC.  So, would I keep it the same?

Comment: @Troy: According to Martin R, this is not the problem if you are using ARC (I did not know), so the problem must be somewhere else.