# iOS - Instance Array not holding data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

For some reason I can't get twitterAccounts to hold another arrays data.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *twitterAccounts;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *chooseTwitterAccountTableView;

- (void)twitterRequest;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _twitterAccounts = [[NSArray alloc]init];

    [self twitterRequest];

}

- (void)twitterRequest {

    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

        if (granted == YES) {

            NSArray *twitterAccountsTemp = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            _twitterAccounts = twitterAccountsTemp;

            NSLog(@"Array first has: %lu elements.", [_twitterAccounts count]);


        }

    }];

}
```

What I don't understand is if I have my viewDidLoad method like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _twitterAccounts = [[NSArray alloc]init];

    [self twitterRequest];

    NSLog(@"After method called: %lu", [_twitterAccounts count]);

}
```

The output is:

```
After method called 0.
Array first has: 1 elements.
```

is it not supposed to be the other way around since I'm calling the method before outputting the amount of elements in the array?

Comment: You did notice that `requestAccessToAccountsWithType` is an *asynchronous* method? - Btw. is it `_accounts` or `_twitterAccounts`? Please copy/paste your real code.

Comment: You're assigning to `_accounts` but logging `_twitterAccounts`... so which one is it?

Comment: also look if granted IS yes ;)

Comment: Why are you creating an empty array in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @HotLicks because I want that empty array to hold the data that aoAccounts holds.

Comment: An empty NSArray by definition doesn't hold any data (and can never hold any data).  You have a basic misconception between a pointer an an object.

Comment: Also, where/how is _accounts defined?

Comment: accounts is defined in the header file: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *accounts;`

Comment: Then what is twitterAccounts?

Comment: @HotLicks but if i create the empty NSArray and set it to another NSArray down in another method, shouldn't the empty NSArray hold the other NSArray's value?

Comment: (Please let us know when you've posted the real code.)

Comment: No, if you create an empty NSArray it will remain empty -- an NSArray is immutable.  If you have a pointer to an NSArray and store a pointer to a different NSArray over the first one, then you can access that second NSArray's contents, but the first array is gone (sort of -- may have leaked).

Comment: @user3000730: Does your `NSLog(@"Array first has ...` display the correct number?

Comment: @MartinR updated code, i explained what happens when the program runs

Comment: So you print the number of elements in the array before you set them into the array???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestAccessToAccountsWithType:` is an *asynchronous* method, which means that it
only *initiates* the request and returns. The completion block
is called *later*, when the request has completed.

Therefore, after calling

```
[self twitterRequest];
```

the `_twitterAccounts` array has not yet been assigned to. When the request has finished
and the completion block is called, `_twitterAccounts = twitterAccountsTemp;` is executed,
and you can update the UI at that point, if necessary.

Comment: is there a solution to get twitterAccounts to hold the data of twitterAccountsTemp?

Comment: @user3000730: Set a breakpoint at `NSArray *twitterAccountsTemp = ...`. You will see that the completion is called some time *later*. That's how asynchronous methods work, there is no way around it.

Comment: ok thanks, my goal was to take the number of elements in that array and create a table view. so i needed the twitterAccounts array to hold it..

Comment: @user3000730: You can update the table view from within the completion block (but on the main thread, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18387414/1187415 for a similar issue).